# Mongo search through nested document array

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo document as follows i want to be able to do make two searches:

1) search for id= 123
2) serach for id= 1234

So the document i need could be the top level or nested.

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "name" : "testName",
   "docs": [
   {
   "id": "1234",
   "name" : "testName4",
   "docs": []
    }
   ]
}
```

So basically i could need the top document or the nested document. Im looking at graph lookup but i dont think that will do what i need, i also looked at aggregates - seems like they would work?

Comment: You can have good reference over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you clarify, what your results should look like?

If you want to search for documents which have an id of "123" or contain a document in "docs" with the id "1234" you could simply query for:

```
db.teststack.find({$or: [{"id": "123"}, {"docs.id": "1234"}]})
```

which will always return the **complete** document.

**EDIT**

See this example I've written:

```
db.teststack.mapReduce(
function(){
    let scanfunction = (passobj) => {
        if(passobj.id === "123") {
            emit("id123", this._id);
        }
        else {
            for(var key in passobj) {
                if(typeof passobj[key] === "object"){
                    scanfunction(passobj[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    scanfunction(this);
}
,
function(key, stuff){
let ret = "";
for(let t1 in stuff)
ret += stuff[t1] + ";";
return ret;
}
,
{
"out": "keys"
}
).find()
```

It simply returns a string containing all ObjectIds which

- a: have the id: "123"
- b: contain a document with id: "123"
- c: contain a document containing a doc.... of which at least one has the id: "123"

The Code is scalable, as it scans all keys of all documents in your database, but therefore it is not performant!

Comment: If you don't know your Database format before, you can use a mapReduce() query to execute JavaScript-Code serverside and display the results as you wish. However, this is not very performant, so I would recommend you to solve your Problem by a different Database-Scheme, where you can predict nestings.

Comment: @user1555190 please review my edit as it fits your needs.